# How can I horizontally centre a single column GridView with a fixed column width?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a GridView which has a single column on smaller devices, and I want to ensure that the column is always centred, whilst maintaining a fixed column width (i.e. not using `stretchMode="columnWidth"`).

Here are the current relavent properties on the GridView:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="230dp"
android:numColumns="1"
android:padding="48dp"
android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="24dp"
```

The grid looks (a bit - excuse my funky representation of the system UI) like this:

[image]

Basically, the column appears with a left alignment. Is there any way that I can get the single column to appear in the centre of the screen, ideally using XML?

I have already tried the following, and they have no impact on the appearance:

- Wrapping the `GridView` in a subclass of `ViewGroup`, such as `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`, setting the `ViewGroup`'s height and width to match_parent and the `GridView`'s to wrap_content

  - Including `layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` as properties of the GridView when attempting the above
- Setting `stretchMode="none"`
- Setting `horizontalSpacing="0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Here are an example. I think it will resolve your problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:columnWidth="230dp"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:padding="48dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="24dp" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. I've tried wrapping the GridView in other subclasses of ViewGroup (LinearLayout, FrameLayout) with various other properties, but it doesn't change the appearance at all.

Comment: As a side note, could you please edit the XML into your answer instead of linking to it?

Comment: By the looks of it, you added: `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`, which also does not change how things look.

Comment: Why don't you use list view instead grid view?

Comment: On larger screened devices, I display 2 or 3 columns. This works fine, because `stretchMode="spacingWidth"` will adjust the horizontal spacing between columns automatically. That's why I asked the question specifically about the single column scenario.

Comment: I think you can define the verticalSpacing in dimen. For small screen device, you can set the value of verticalSpacing = "0dp"

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean horizontalspacing? In the example I gave above, I omitted it because it is irrelevant when I have just one column. The default value is 0.

Comment: Have you try to set android:stretchMode="none"

Comment: Yes, I have. I should have added a list of things that I've already tried in my question - I'll do that now.